# How to get an apk file in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, import, apk

How to import or copy apk file to eclipse,i had tried importing but i could not as i dint get the correct procedure right.

I had created an app and i signed-in and exported it from eclipse....

After few days i thought that it is useless in eclipse so i deleted it from eclipse.

Now i want to update that particular app  file

So how do i get it back to the eclipse with all the source code and all.

If there is a procedure please give it step by step as i am a newbie.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of getting the source code from an APK.

You can use a tool like [APKTool](http://www.miui-au.com/add-ons/apktool/).

You should save the source code if you plan to edit it later on.

Comment: then should i create that app again ?

Comment: You can try to use APKTool. I have not tried it. But in the future don't delete the source code if you plan to edit it later on. And remember to save the keys you use to sign the APK. You will have to sign it with the same keys to update the APK to a new version.

Comment: i have the keys and source codes copied in text file,so will this help me to create a new android application with the same codes? I had published the app in google play and i want to update that,will this same codes and key help to update the app?

Comment: Yes. You need to export with the same keys to update the app on Google Play.

Comment: thank you very much........                                                         I even wanted to know how do we change the icon in eclipse?              I had chose a icon when i was creating new android application, but i want to change it is there any way to change?